# Missing rows when exporting query in MS Access to MS Excel using VBA

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have a query in Ms Access that runs with 227,288 rows. I made a command button which can export the query into Excel. I've searched and found this code

```
Private Sub Export_Click()
    Dim rst         As DAO.Recordset
    Dim excelApp    As Object
    Dim sht         As Object
    Dim fldHeadings As DAO.Field

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("acct file", dbOpenDynaset)

    Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    On Error Resume Next

    Set Wbk = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(book1)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Or Len(book1) = 0 Then
        Set Wbk = excelApp.Workbooks.Add
        Set sht = Wbk.Worksheets("CSC Landed")
        If Len(sheet1) > 0 Then
            sht.Name = Left("acct file", 34)
        End If
    End If

    Set sht = Wbk.Worksheets.Add
    If Len(sheet1) > 0 Then
        sht.Name = Left("acct file", 34)
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    excelApp.Visible = True

    On Error GoTo Errorhandler

    For Each fldHeadings In rst.Fields
        excelApp.ActiveCell = fldHeadings.Name
        excelApp.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next

    rst.MoveFirst
    sht.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
    sht.Range("1:1").Select

    excelApp.Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With excelApp.Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = -4108
        .VerticalAlignment = -4108
        .WrapText = False
        With .Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 10
        End With
    End With

    excelApp.ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    With excelApp.ActiveWindow
        .FreezePanes = False
        .ScrollRow = 1
        .ScrollColumn = 1
    End With
    sht.Rows("2:2").Select
    excelApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

    With sht
        .Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing

Exit Sub

Errorhandler:
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

However, when export is done it only exports 496 rows. I've search and tried different attempts, still the rows I'm getting is only 496.  I'm also looking into preferences in VB.

I'm very new in Access. I've done several research but still I couldn't do it.

[image]

Comment: Hi Anne. We don't add [solved] to the title here, that's what the tick symbol is for. I also add "posted on behalf of" to my wiki answer to make it clear that it was not me that solved it - if you would like to post your own answer I am happy to delete mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I've got it working by

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
    "acct file", "C:\Users\user\Desktop\acctfile.xlsx", True
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're running the Export_Click code from within Microsoft Access, you can use the following code to invoke the "Output To" action of the DoCmd object:

```
Private Sub Export_Click()

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "acct file", acFormatXLSX, , True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ric, should I stick with previous codes and just add your code? thanks..

Comment: I've tried the code... still I'm getting the divide the rows.. only getting 400++ rows. :(

Comment: hi @ricardo-gerbaudo got to export the limit 65,000++ rows... I've tried using transferspreadsheet. but had trouble doing so. got any ideas guys?